# Issue with Next.js Middleware Redirection Logic

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am working on a Next.js application where I have implemented custom middleware to handle authentication and access control. The middleware checks if the user has a valid token and if they are trying to access public or private routes appropriately. The middleware should redirect users to the dashboard if they try to access public routes with a token and redirect to the login page if they try to access private routes without a token.

However, I am experiencing an issue with the redirection logic in the middleware. The logs show that the middleware correctly detects the path and token status and reaches the point where the redirection should happen. Still, the redirection itself is not working as expected. Instead of redirecting, the middleware continues with the regular flow, leading to an incorrect rendering or potential access to unauthorized routes.

Here is the relevant code snippet for the middleware:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { sidebarItems } from "./presentation/components/sidebars/sidebar/sidebar-items";
import { IResponseDto } from "./domain/dto";
import { IAccessByToken } from "./infrastructure/redux/apis/users";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const isPublicPath = path === "/login" || path === "/";
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value  || "";

  if (isPublicPath && token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
  }

  if (!isPublicPath && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.nextUrl));
  }

  const data: IResponseDto<IAccessByToken> = await (
    await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}~users/auth/access?token=${token}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
  ).json();

  const itemSidebar = sidebarItems
    .filter((item) => {
      if (item.role) {
        return item.role.some((role) => data?.data.accessKeys?.items.includes(role));
      }
      return true;
    })
    .map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      children: item.children?.filter((child) => {
        if (child.role) {
          return child.role.some((role) => data?.data.accessKeys?.items.includes(role));
        }
        return true;
      }),
    }));

    itemSidebar.forEach((item) => {
      console.log("1");
      if (item.route && !item.route.includes(path)) {
        console.log("2");
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
      }
      console.log("3");
      item.children?.forEach((child) => {
        console.log("4");
        if (child.route && !child.route.includes(path)) {
          console.log("5");
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.nextUrl));
        }
        console.log("6");
      });
    });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/dashboard",
    "/add-purchase",
    "/brands",
    "/add-product",
    "/product-list",
    "/edit-product/:path*",
    "/purchase-list/:path*",
    "/add-leave",
    "/leave-list",
    "/my-leaves",
    "/public/:path*",
    "/login",
  ],
};
```

The logs indicate that the middleware is reaching the point of redirection, but the redirection doesn't occur as expected. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm using the NextResponse.redirect() method or with the config matcher.

Could you please review the code and logs provided and help me identify the problem with the redirection logic in the middleware? Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any additional information is required to understand the problem better.

Comment: "Doesn't occur as expected", this is very vague. What are you expecting to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: in my case I have an `infinite loop`, I am using the ClerkAuth middleware, I have already conditioned if the path is already found in `req.nextUrl.pathname` but the error persists.